# stylesheet is not readable error after installation

Tags: themes

I have downloaded and installed the latest Wordpress version 4.2.2 on my Windows machine with nginx and run it locally.
The installation was successful and I can open the website and and administration page too.
Although I have a clean new installation, when I open the window "Themes", I see an error at the top "ERROR: Stylesheet is not readable" and the standard themes are listed as "Broken":

- twentyfifteen
- twentyfourteen
- twentythirteen

What might be the reason? and the solution too?

best regards.

Comment: Are the files readable? If not re-upload the files. Also check the file permission.

Comment: The files are readable, writable, executable, all permissions. I have it running only my local computer, not deployed anywhere.